# search a doc with its ID in 2 different Firestore collection at backend in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have the ID of the DOC, is there any query to search that doc in *2* *different* *collection*, am doing this check in my code but is there any firebase query to do same.

Comment: You have to do the queries one by one. There is no such API support.

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 1):

If the collections that you want to search have the same name, you can [use a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to search both of then (well actually, you'll be searching all collections with that name).

If the collections have different names, there is no way to search them both with a single query. You'll have to do a separate query for each collection, and then merge the results in your application code.